# How to access Parent Route from Child Tab Navigator in React Navigation in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a Parent SwitchNavigator which has two screens:
 1. HomeScreen 
 2. DashBoard

Also my dashboard screen is actually a drawer Navigator that consists of other screens like: 
 1. Ongoing News
 2. Profile Edit
 3. Logout

Now in Logout If i write this.props.navigation.navigate("Home") it takes me to the Ongoing News screen which the home in this current child drawer navigator route... But I want to jump to the higher route i.e. the parent route of switch navigator and I want to go to the HomeScreen there instead of being in this route how can I achieve this??

I am beginner so please if you can explain in as simple words as possible that would be great... :)

Comment: Can you edit the question to add your router file/routes definition so that it is easier to understand the hierarchy of the routes?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO!
Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to improve the quality of your question.